# how to create a hyperlink for column in sql server 2008 which points to Excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a link for a column which points to Excel sheet.

If I click on that column than Excel sheet should open.

Is it possible in SQL? If possible, please let me know about it

Comment: You mean clicking the column in Management Studio or where?

Comment: You can **store** the link in SQL Server - yes - but SQL Server isn't a GUI app - I don't know what you mean by *if I click on that* ..... click on that in what?? SQL Server Management Studio? Your own application using the SQL Server data??